# NebulaGraph Using Match with Where and Contains

Tags: nebula-graph

I'am asking my "Newbie" question here.

I'am going into NebulaGraph and I have some trouble with querying, I may be stupid but I also don't get the documentation (either syntax or example, and I can't found a way to match my need)

SO.
Admiting I got the following Vertice and Edge.

```
Tag : Person(Name string, Age string, Sexe string);'
Emotion(Name string);'
Edge : HAS_EMOTION (relationship string)'# Person to Emotion

Inserted with
INSERT VERTEX Person(Name, Age, Sexe) VALUES "Alice_Watson":("Alice Watson", "32", "Female");
INSERT VERTEX Emotion(Name) VALUES "Curiosity":("Curiosity");
INSERT EDGE HAS_EMOTION VALUES "Alice_Watson"->"Curiosity":("Alice expressed curiosity about LLM");
```

I want to do something like :

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[r:HAS_EMOTION]->(e:Emotion) WHERE e.Name == "Curiosity" AND r.relationship  CONTAINS "LLM" RETURN p.Name;
```

But it return

> Empty table.

However,

```
FETCH PROP ON HAS_EMOTION "Alice_Watson" -> "Curiosity" YIELD properties(edge)
```

return

> {relationship: "Alice expressed curiosity about LLM"}

So the Edge does exist.

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[r:HAS_EMOTION]->(e:Emotion) WHERE r.relationship  CONTAINS "LLM" RETURN p;
```

return

> ("Alice_Watson" :Person{Age: "32", Name: "Alice Watson", Sexe:
> "Female"})

AND BOTH

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[r:HAS_EMOTION]->(e:Emotion) WHERE e.Name == "Curiosity" AND r.relationship CONTAINS "LLM" RETURN p;
MATCH (p:Person)-[r:HAS_EMOTION]->(e:Emotion) WHERE e.Name == "Curiosity" RETURN p;
```

return

```
empty table
```

QUESTION:
I don't get why p.Name return empty but p doesn't.
I don't get why I can't exact match "Curiosity" since the node exist.

Hope someone can help me here
Cheers,
KL